# How to upload a CSV file to a new tab(sheet) in the google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I want to write a script that can automatically upload the CSV file to a google spreadsheet.
And following is my code to realize it:

```
import csv

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheetName = "abc" 
spreadsheet = client.open("abc")
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
content = list(csv.reader(open('123.csv')))
worksheet.append_rows(content, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

However, this script can only append the values under the same sheet, and my boss asked me to upload CSV to a new tab under the same spreadsheet every day. For example, today I am going to upload CSV data to CSV-to-Google-Sheet, tomorrow I am going to upload it to sheet1. Please check the screenshot I attached.

I googled the related information for hours but find nothing useful. What should I do?

As you can see there are two tabs at the bottom of the sheet, one is called CSV-to-Google-Sheet, the other is called sheet1:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to put the data each day on a new page, my suggestion would be for you to create a new page with the name of today's date and then add the values:

```python
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
dicter = 'client_secret.json'
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(dicter, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

id_file = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(id_file)

today = datetime.date.today()
worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=str(today), rows=1000, cols=26)
worksheet.update('A1',[['test','test_2']])
```

*Additional note*:
Always try to use the file *ID* to open instead of using the name, it's a bit risky if you or someone else edits the name (it's easier for someone to edit the file name than you delete the file and create another one).

The *ID* → `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I used can be found at:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the 'sh' on line 5?

Comment: Hi @TryingToLearnSomething ```sh.``` has been edited to ```spreadsheet.``` for better viewing, it is the specification of the file opened by you.
If it solves your problem, please mark the answer as a solution and if you liked the approach, give an additional upvote.

Comment: Ummm, it shows me an error "Object of type date is not JSON serializable" for worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=today, rows=1000, cols=26), I guess it's date package problem?

Comment: @TryingToLearnSomething could you please test with ```title=str(today)```?

Comment: @TryingToLearnSomething test using ```spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title=str(today), rows=1000, cols=26)```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I don't have a 15 reputations now XD so I cannot give you a upvote, but I will do so immediately after I got the 15 reputations!

Comment: @TryingToLearnSomething I made some edits and additions to the answer.